# What does this LUA line mean? ""%i (%.3f GHz)" %{ f.channel, f.mhz / 1000 })"

Tags: lua

I have a question concerning to this snippet of code

```
ch = s:taboption("general", Value, "channel", translate("Channel"))
ch:value("auto", translate("auto"))
for _, f in ipairs(iw and iw.freqlist or { }) do
    if not f.restricted then
       ch:value(f.channel, "%i (%.3f GHz)" %{ f.channel, f.mhz / 1000 }) //this line?
    end
end
```

What is doing the line?

```
ch:value(f.channel, "%i (%.3f GHz)" %{ f.channel, f.mhz / 1000 })
```

I think it is assigning some value to ch but I cannot understand which one, because I cannot understand completely what this section does *"%i (%.3f GHz)" %{ f.channel, f.mhz / 1000 }*

Thanks in advance!

Complete code

```
-- Check whether there is a client interface on the same radio,
-- if yes, lock the channel choice as the station will dicatate the freq
local has_sta = nil
local _, net
for _, net in ipairs(wdev:get_wifinets()) do
    if net:mode() == "sta" and net:id() ~= wnet:id() then
        has_sta = net
        break
    end
end

if has_sta then
    ch = s:taboption("general", DummyValue, "choice", translate("Channel"))
    ch.value = translatef("Locked to channel %d used by %s",
        has_sta:channel(), has_sta:shortname())
else
    ch = s:taboption("general", Value, "channel", translate("Channel"))
    ch:value("auto", translate("auto"))
    -- for _, f in ipairs(iw and iw.freqlist or { }) do
    for _.iw.chanlist, f in ipairs(iw and iw.freqlist or iw.channels) do
        if not f.restricted then
            ch:value(f.channel, "%i (%.3f GHz)" %{ f.channel, f.mhz / 1000 })
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: that is not bash. What does the shebang say or the name of the file etc? How do you run the code?

Comment: You were right, it is Luci

Comment: Looks like Lua, but yes, please let us know what the shebang says :) As to `"%i (%.3f GHz)"`, looks like string-formatting

Comment: first line of the file, e.g. something like this `#!/bin/bash` see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

Comment: The first line is `--[[
LuCI - Lua Configuration Interface`

Comment: ok, then it's lua. Please update the title of the question and the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"%i (%.3f GHz)" %{ f.channel, f.mhz / 1000 }
```

1. The `%i` will parse an argument as integer.
2. `%.3f` formats the second argument as a floating point number with 3 decimal places.
3. `%{}` defines the arguments being passed to previous string for formatting.

   - First parameter is `f.channel`
   - Second argument is `f.mhz/1000`.

---

```
ch:value( f.value, ... )
```

is same as the following:

```
ch.value( ch, f.value, ... )
```

Comment: Also, in Lua, the `:` operator is syntactic-sugar for the 'dot' operator; i.e. object-oriented method calls. So `ch` is an object of some type and `value()` is one of its methods.

Comment: @amrith92 hmm, though it wasn't mentioned in question title. Edited anyhow (^_^)/

Comment: Nice :) The OP said: `I think it is assigning some value to ch but I cannot understand which one,`, so mentioned it just to clarify that

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `%` operator was defined for strings via `__mod` metamethod of strings' metatable

```
getmetatable''.__mod = function(str, tbl)
   return str:format((table.unpack or unpack)(tbl))
end
```